# Probability puzzle on three people rolling a die

Tags: probability

Given three players A, B, C, taking turns to roll a fair die in the order A B C A B C A B ....

What's the probability of that the occurrence of second 6 is in A's turn?
My approach was

Let $F_6$ and $S_6$ be the r.v's for the first and second occurrences of 6 respectively. 
$$\begin{align}P(S_6 = A) &= P(S_6 = A \cap F_6 = A)  + P(S_6 = A \cap F_6 = B)  
+ P(S_6 = A \cap F_6 = C)\\ 
&= P(F_6=A)P(S_6=A | F_6=A) +P(F_6=B)P(S_6=A | F_6=B)\\
&+P(F_6=C)P(S_6=A | F_6=C)\\
&= 3(\frac{5}{6} P(F_6 = A))^2 \end{align}\\$$

Here I am using the following relations

$$\begin{align}P(F_6=B) &= \frac{5}{6}P(F_6=A),\\ P(F_6=C)&=(\frac{5}{6})^2P(F_6=A),\\\text{and}\quad P(S_6=A | F_6=A)&=(\frac{5}{6})^2P(F_6=A)\\P(S_6=A | F_6=B)&=\frac{5}{6}P(F_6=A)\\P(S_6=A | F_6=C)&=P(F_6=A)\end{align}$$

My reasoning for the first relation is that

$P(\text{first occurrence of B in seq ABCABC...}) = P(\text{A doesnt throw 6}) P(\text{first occurrence of B in seq BCABCABC...})$\

By symmetry
$P(\text{first occurrence of B in seq BCABCABC...})=P(\text{first occurrence of A in seq ABCABCAB...})$

I am unsure if my method is correct. Please help me verify this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks right to me so far.  Why haven't you finished it?

Comment: @saulspatz The rest of the relations follow similar logic. calculating the probability of first occurrence of 6 in A's turn is a simple geometric series. Hence, i left it there. I was thinking if there is a much cleaner way to solve the above problem.

Comment: Then I think you've got it.

Comment: This is not the same problem.  That problem asked if A was the second person to roll a 6, this problem asks if A rolled the second six.  (In the suggested duplicate, the first person to roll a 6 could have done so multiple times before the second person did.)